# Passing form data between pages with angular routing

Tags: angularjs, forms, ngroute, ng-view

I want to build an app which has 2 tabs, one will have a form, and the other tab is for reviewing the data filled in the form.
I have a navigation, with 2 links, which are changing a ng-view div.
My problem is whenever I click on the review link, it resets all the data I have filled in the form.
The controller js:

```
var MainApp = angular.module("MainApp",['ngRoute']);
   function appRouteConfig($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/',{
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'add.html',
        }).
        when('/review',{
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'review.html',
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}
var MainCtrl = MainApp.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.campaign = {cName:''};
});
```

A form input for example:

```
<tr> 
    <td>Campaign Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="cName" ng-model='campaign.cName' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

When I change the view from add.html (where the form is) to review.html all the data in the form just resets, so no data shows on my review page, and when I switch back to the add.html view, all the inputs are blank.

Is there a way I can keep the data when I switch between views?

Comment: Either post them to the server or store them in a service. The former can be made to survive page reloads, the latter cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean browser tabs, then i would suggest looking into session/local storage but if you mean maintaining data between two views, then you would create a separate service that both views (aka controllers) have access to. A new controller instance is created when the view loads which is why you lose your data.

[Egghead has great tutorials on all things angular](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers)

Comment: I meant passing data between views. I've made a service and I have a controller for each view. Inside the service I've created an array which I intend to contain all the inputs from the form. now in the controller which controls the form view, I've made a binding between the inputs and the array (serviceName.newForm = {data,data,data,etc...}), but it just updates the controller though, not the service, so again when I switch views it deletes all the data.. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In above example, campaign.cName is bound to $scope, which get's instantiated with the controller, so will be lost when switching between views. Create a service with the campaign object, and inject the service to the controller. Binding to the service object will persist data between views/controllers.